# Joi nested when

Tags: javascript, joi

```js
const schema = {
    a: Joi.any(),
    b: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false),
    c: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false)
}
```

How can I fix the abovementioned Joi schema to matches the following rules

- One of `b` or `c` can be `true` at the same time
- When `b` or `c` is `true`, `a` is `forbidden` otherwise `a` is `required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Joi.object( {
  a: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false),
  b: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false),
  c: Joi.string().when(
    'a', {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.when(
        'b', {
          is: false,
          then: Joi.string().required()
        }
      )
    }
  ),
})
```

I tried nested `when` before asking question, but it not working before because of the order of rules

```js
Joi.object( {
  c: Joi.string().when(
    'a', {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.when(
        'b', {
          is: false,
          then: Joi.string().required()
        }
      )
    }
  ),
  a: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false),
  b: Joi
      .boolean()
      .default(false),
})
```

the `default` value in the second schema is not set when the `when` is checking, So If you validate an empty object `{}`, the first schema has `Validation Error: "c" is required` error while the second `Passed` with `{a: false, b: false}`

I opened an issue here https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2683